# Django: How to filter and display categories for author in post

Tags: django

Django: How to filter and display categories for author in post
I guess there's something wrong with the get_queryset Category.objects.filter(post_author=username)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    exercisename = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hour = models.IntegerField(default=0 )
    min = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='Files')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_Posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/') 


def userpost(request, username):
    
    context = { 
        'Category': Category.objects.filter(post_author=username),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/user_Posts.html', context)
```

Comment: Sir your `Category table ` isnt even connected to `Post table ` how do you want to get query like this when there isnt any relation between 2 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter your category like this:

```py
Category.objects.filter(post_author__username=username)
```

When you call `ForeignKey` directly, it expects object, not field. So you use `__{field_name}` to call exact field in Django ORM.

Also, your category has no relation to `Post` model, or has `Author` relation at all...

Comment: hove error FieldError at /user/1
Cannot resolve keyword 'post_author' into field. Choices are: description, id, image, name, post

Comment: Use `.filter(post__author__username=username)`. It should work.

Comment: it's work thank, I have only items 3  in Category but give more 7 how don't repeat it

Comment: Use: `.filter(post__author__username=username).distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a relation between Post and Category in order to make the query work.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    exercisename = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hour = models.IntegerField(default=0 )
    min = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='Files')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_Posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

```py
def userpost(request, username):
    # this gives the username's posts and change the django query result 
    # to a python list a list of categories
    author_posts_categories = Post.objects.filter(author=username).\
       values_list('category',flat=True)
    
    context = { 
        # this gives you the selected user categories from post
        'Category':Category.objects.filter(id__in = author_posts_categories ),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/user_Posts.html', context)
```